# Как вывести в документ результат XPath запроса из XML ( VBA Word )

Tags: xml, запрос, vba, xpath

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim xmlFile As String

Dim XDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xmlSelection As IXMLDOMSelection

XDoc.async = False
XDoc.validateOnParse = True

XDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

Dim Query As String
Dim Variable As String

Query = " //Geometry/Group/Shape/@name"

Set xmlSelection = XDoc.SelectNodes(Query)

Selection.TypeText (" Query ")
Selection.TypeParagraph
```

Вот пример кода, где я пытаюсь вывести результат, но вместо него выводится "Query"

Буду крайне благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Напишите без кавычек

```
Selection.TypeText (Query)
```